# How do I get the path to the current file in a Shared COM Office Add-in?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, c#-4.0

I am wondering how I can get the path to the current file that is open in a Shared COM Add-in for Microsoft Office. I am using Visual Studio 2010 with C#

I know this question has been asked, "How do I get the file in an Excel add-in?" but that does not answer my question.

Comment: I think the answer depends on which app you're specifically wondering about?

Comment: It's a Shared Plugin. That means that it runs in all Office Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is the correct way to do it:

`this.Application.ActiveDocument.Name`

and

`this.Application.ActiveDocument.Path`